# naming convention for methods that transfer ownership

Tags: java, naming-conventions, transfer, getter, ownership

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo
{
    private Bar x;

    // ...

    public Bar getAndResetX()
    {
        Bar result = x;
        x = new Bar();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there an established naming conventions for such methods? Like `yieldX`, `transferX` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to have the convention **Adopt** and **Orphan** as a prefix to provide intention in the method name (taken from Taligent book on C++).

```
Bar b = foo.orphanBar(); // take Bar out of Foo
foo.adoptBar(b); // put it right back in
```

You could use something similar to provide ownership clues to the objects. Quite frankly though I would stick with the Java convention of using **add** and **remove**. They provide enough intention and other programmers will not need to read a comment explaining the new convention.

```
Bar b = foo.removeBar(); // take Bar out of Foo
foo.addBar(b); // put it right back in
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is a naming convention for such methods. IMHO, I would use the verb *take* (e.g. `takeX()`). For more information regarding method naming conventions, see [JLS §6.8.3 Method Names](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#9322).

But in all honesty, it's really just a matter of opinion. If you're really that concerned, I'd recommend you browse the [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html) for methods that are functionally equivalent, and then model your method name after those.

Comment: I was thinking of the same verb. It's used in JavaSpaces to refer to acquiring and removing an object from a space.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla's native smart-pointer classes use the method `forget()` to indicate a transfer of ownership:

```c
already_AddRefed<nsIFoo> GetFoo() {
    nsCOMPtr<nsIFoo> foo = ...
    ...
    return foo.forget();
}
```